# Can I use Mathematica 9.0 to open an MX file produced by Mathematica 10?

Tags: version-10, version-9, compatibility

I have used Mathematica 10 installed on a workstation of university's lab to run a `NDSlove` code that produced a .mx file. Then I copy the `.mx` file to my laptop which has Mathematica 9.0. When I try to open it by `Get["C:\\xxx.mx"]`, Mathematica prompts

> DumpGet::bgnew: "File !(\"C:\\data.mx\") has been written by a newer version of DumpSave and cannot be loaded."

Or is there any way to force Mathematica 10 to save a .mx file which can be opened using Mathematica 9.0 front end?

Comment: No, MX files written by v10 cannot be reliably opened by v9.  MX doesn't even have cross-operating-system compatibility in v9.  Use a different format, e.g. `Compress` and export to string.

Comment: @Szabolcs shouldn't this be a part of docs or details&options? They only say this in "MX" docs not in `DumpSave` page: `MX files cannot be exchanged between different operating systems or versions of the Wolfram System.`. And MX page is not linked in `DumpSave`. Moreover they say this in V10 too which is not really the case anymore as we know. Should this be reported?

Comment: @Szabolcs, Thanks. You mean after the calculation of `NDSlove` with v10 I could use `Compress` to save the `InterpolationFunction` object as string? Then how can I open the "string" with v9?

Comment: @lxy: that is indeed what Szabolcs meant, something like `Save[filename,Compress@expr]` to save and `Uncompress@Get[filename]` should do the trick. Unfortunately not only file formats but also some implementation details of `InterpolatingFunction` have changed between version 9 and 10 so there might be problems to read a v10 `InterpolatingFunction` with v9. You probably need to extract the grid and values and save those if you need to transfer a `NDSolve` solution vom v10 to v9...

Comment: @Albert,thank you for the clarification!

Comment: @lxy: you are welcome, and in case you get this working: I wanted to assure you are aware that it is common and welcomed on this site that you answer your own question and accept it so others can participate in what you learned...

Comment: @AlbertRetey, I have install MMA v10 on my laptop, but I still can not open `.mx` file which was saved by MMA v10 on a workstation. The OS on my laptop and workstation are both Win7-64bit. This is how I saved `InterpolationFunction` in the workstation and open it on my laptop:`DumpSave["filename.mx", "Global`"]` and `Get["C:\\....\\filename.mx"]`. Now the MMA version and OS are all the same...

Comment: Are you using the same releases on both machines? Have you tried to load the mx file on the workstation, just as an additional check? What exactly is not working, are you seeing error messages or just not getting the definitions you expect? It's quite difficult to remote debug these kind of problems, so you'd need to provide as much information as possible. Are you sure that both are actually using a 64bit Mathematica? I think that should nowadays always be the case but as that still makes a difference it might be worth to check...

Comment: @AlbertRetey, The issue exactly is: laptop seems to load the `.mx` file, but can not plot. I mean the plot is just an empty frame without any error message. Yes, workstation can read the `.mx` file. I am sure they are both 64-bit. Another silly problem: how to check the release of MMA V.10 on my laptop? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: to check the version evaluate `$VersionNumber` and `$ReleaseNumber`. What happens if you just evaluate the variable on the laptop that should hold the interpolating function? Does that show something and if so, what?

Comment: @AlbertRetey, the version on the workstation and laptop are both v10. However, the release on workstation is 1 and on laptop is 0. When I just evaluate variable on the laptop, it take a very long time, so I abort it.

Comment: I have no indication that the release difference matters but I also cannot exclude that, especially since I think there were at least some fixes done for InterpolatingFunctions between those releases. I'd suggest to either extract the grid and values and save those or use the Compress/Uncompress cycle to transfer the results...